# Find $\lambda $ such $B,M$ and $N$ are colinear points?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> $ABCDEF :$ Regular hexagon and $M\in [AC]$ , $N\in [CE]$ such :
> $\frac{AM}{AC}=\frac{CN}{CE}=\lambda $ where $\lambda >0$.
>
> Find $\lambda $ such $B,M$ and $N$ are colinear points?

I don't know how to start this problem.

Maybe we should use angle $120°$ and $60°$

I need ideas or hints to approach it!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTi06.png)

This solution by Apostolis Manoloudis :
[image]

But I don't understand why he starte with $AB=AM$ ?
Can someone explain to me this solution
If any one have another way drop here

Answer (score 1):

(New redaction of this paragraph). You are right when doubting about the correctness of the reasoning of this person. No basis for saying that $AM=AP$ !!! **Mr Manoloudis makes an erroneous circular reasoning (petitio principii)**. This could be caught up in the following way. Let us take the sides of the hexagon as unit length. First apply Al Kashi's theorem to triangle $ABC$ : $AC^2=AB^2+BC^2-2 AB.BC \cos(120°)$ giving $AC=\sqrt{3}$. Now, **making the assumption** that the reversed ratio $\tfrac{1}{\lambda}=\tfrac{AC}{AM}=\sqrt{3}$, then $AM=1$, therefore $AM=AB$, triangle $BAM$ is isosceles ; having summit angle $30°$, base angle $AMB$ is $75°$, and we can resume...

Remark : angle-chasing based proofs aren't appreciated by geometers because they are figure-dependent, thus prone to errors.

---

Here is a completely different proof using barycentrical coordinates in triangle $ACE$.

What are barycentrical coordinates ? They are based on the fact, proved in lectures, that every point $M$ in the plane is completely determined by the list of weights (= degrees of attraction) $(a,c,e)$ (normalized as percentages, i.e., with $a+c+e=1$) to be placed on $A$, $C$ and $E$ resp. in such a way that $M$ is the barycenter of these points with these weights, corresponding to notation

$$M=aA+cC+eE.$$

For example, the center of gravity of $ACE$ has baryc. coord. $(\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3})$, the midpoint of $AC$ has baryc. coord. $(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},0)$. Baryc. coordinates are all positive for points inside triangle $ACE$ whereas, for points outside this triangle, some coordinates are negative exhibiting a "repulsion" by some vertices.

As $M=(1-\lambda)A+\lambda C$, the barycentrical coord. of $M$ are

$$((1-\lambda), \ \lambda, \ 0)\tag{1}$$

For the same reason, relationship $N=(1-\lambda)C+\lambda E$ gives the following baryc. coord. for $N$ :

$$(0,\ (1-\lambda), \ \lambda)\tag{2}$$

Last point $B$ has baryc. coord. (see proof below) :

$$(2/3,\ 2/3, \ -1/3)\tag{3}$$

The necessary and sufficient condition for $M, \ N, \ B$ to be aligned is that the determinant of their baryc. coord. is zero:

$$\begin{vmatrix}0&(1-\lambda)&\lambda\\(1-\lambda)&\lambda&0\\2/3&2/3&-1/3\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Expanding, one gets $1-3\lambda^2=0$, therefore

> $$\lambda=\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

($\lambda=- \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ could be a solution if $M$, resp. $N$ weren't constrained to be in line segments $[AC]$, resp.  $[CE]$).

**Proof of relationship (3) :**

$$2(\vec{BA}+\vec{BC})=\vec{BE} \ \iff \ 2(A-B+C-B)=E-B \ \iff \ B=\tfrac{2}{3}A+\tfrac{2}{3}C+(-\tfrac{1}{3})E$$

Comment: I have an alternate way to prove this issue. But I wait first for your reaction. Besides, could you give a refrence for this problem and its "solution" ?

Comment: Thank you very much sir @jean Marie , but can you explain to me whyand how $M,N,B$ to be aligned is that the determinant of their baryc. coord $=0$ is this rule ? Or theorem

Comment: In fact, the general theorem is that the determinant of the baryc. coordinates of 3 points $M,N,P$ is the area of triangle $MNP$ divided by the area of reference triangle (here $ACE$). Therefore, if the 3 points $M,N,P$ are aligned, the area in the numerator is $0$. And the quotient is $0$.

Comment: I have written in a new way the first paragraph.

Comment: Sir @jean thank you very much , very nice done